# Method not allowed error 405 for Swagger UI setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am unable to use `SWAGGER-UI` at my Spring boot application.

actuator(`/actuator`) and docs url(`'/v2/api-docs'`) are working fine.

But at swagger url `/swagger-ui.html` I get error saying `Method Not Allowed` and Error code as `405`

Swagger Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

Maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error Screen
[image]

Comment: Have you included the `springfox-boot-starter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue because of existing APIs

I had an Existing API at controller which was like

```
http://localhost:8080/{PathParam}
```

I changed it to (Add any string before path params)

```
http://localhost:8080/domain/{PathParam}
```

**and the issue was resolved !!!**